Can't install tensorflow_federated
I'm trying to install tensorflow_federated and keep getting "encountered an error when generating package metadata"... please help!
I've been using this command to install - pip install --upgrade tensorflow-federated and my python version is 3.10.13.
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/sl/yn34_0hx3pbcpmr7_27g57rc0000gn/T/pip-install-q2k8bkzy/absl-py_4bd385a59f244b81b536dee877914526/setup.py", line 34, in <module>
          raise RuntimeError('Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.')
      RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I've been using this command to install - pip install --upgrade tensorflow-federated and my python version is 3.10.13.
